# Javascript block removing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I really need to remove some block with the help of js. Is it possible not to hide some block, but remove it at all?

Because I have a field wich user will not be able to see if he selected "no" in my selectbox, but JQuery validation anyway sends message that this field is empty.

I have this:

```
     $(function () {
          $("#wichonepmtofollow").hide();

          $("#particularpmselect").change(function () {
              // find the selected one
              var selectedCountry = $(this).val();

              if (selectedCountry == "yes") {
                  $("#wichonepmtofollow").show();
              }
              // otherwise hide it
              else {
                  $("#wichonepmtofollow").hide();
              }
          });
      });
```

And this:

```
<div id="wichonepmtofollow">
    <div class="section" id="inputdiv">
        <span class="fieldname">Which one?</span>
        <input type="text" id="wichonepm" name="wichonepm" title="can't be empty" class="required" minlength="1"/> <!-- Nessesary to be filled-->
           <script type="text/javascript">
               var wichonepm = new LiveValidation('wichonepm');
               wichonepm.add(Validate.Presence);
           </script>  
    </div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Like instead of $("#pleasespecify").hide(); make something like $("#pleasespecify").**remove**(); or something else?

Comment: I guess you have not searched for [`jquery remove`](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=jquery+remove) have you?

Comment: Recommendation: drop LiveValidation and use the jQuery Validation plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), which makes it easy to define rules to not validate hidden fields.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#pleasespecify").remove();
```

is correct ([docs here](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)).

Or, you can empty the parent:

```
$("#wichonepmtofollow").empty();
```

**EDIT** (due to comments by OP):

You can keep an object you've removed, e.g.:

```
var savedObj = $("#pleasespecify").remove();
```

And then you can append it later:

```
$("#wichonepmtofollow").append(savedObj);
```

Note that this will also unbind all events that are bound to the associated DOM element. To keep all the events bound, you can use jQuery's [detatch](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) method.

Comment: No, it does not work how it should. It removes my block. But does not return!   if (selectedCountry == "yes") {
                  $("#wichonepmtofollow").show();
              }

Comment: @FlashTrava - can you correct the id's in your javascript and html, or post the connected pieces?

Comment: So you want to DESTROY it and then bring it back later via show()? Maybe if you store it as a variable and append later ...

Comment: Yes, i want to destroy it. And than to create if user set "yes" in selectbox. I'm not so good in JS. Could you shom how it should look like?

Answer (score 0):

*[Updated based on user comments]*

Hold the html temporary in a variable -

```
if (selectedCountry == "yes") {
    $("#wichonepmtofollow").html(temHtml);
}
else {
    temHtml = $("#wichonepmtofollow").html();
    $("#wichonepmtofollow").html('');
}
```

Globally declare the temHtml

```
var temHtml;
```

Comment: The same. It does not work how it should. It removes my block. But does not return! if (selectedCountry == "yes") { $("#wichonepmtofollow").show(); }

Answer (score 0):

To store html in a temporary variiable and then remove from page:

```
var tempHtml;//declare tempHtml outside other script code so it's available later
```

then, instead of `$("#wichonepmtofollow").hide();` use this:

```
 tempHtml = $("#wichonepmtofollow").html();
 $("#wichonepmtofollow").html(''); //empty the container
```

To reinstate the html later:

```
 $("#wichonepmtofollow").html(tempHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

there's no need to destroy anything, just enable or disable it, and it will not be validated if it's hidden:

```
$(function () {
      $("#wichonepmtofollow").hide();
      $('#wichonepm').attr('disabled',true);

      $("#particularpmselect").change(function () {
          // find the selected one
          var selectedCountry = $(this).val();

          if (selectedCountry == "yes") {
              $("#wichonepmtofollow").show();
              $('#wichonepm').attr('disabled',false);
          }
          // otherwise hide it
          else {
              $("#wichonepmtofollow").hide();
              $('#wichonepm').attr('disabled',true);
          }
      });
  });
```